# Excel filtering rows and columns

Tags: excel, filter, rows

I have data in rows and columns for either H or M or L and I want to filter out any Hs that are in the rows and columns. Only problem is the row has a main heading and then a sub heading. Any ideas please how I do this?

Comment: Highlight your 2nd row and then Filter..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highlight the whole table except for the Main Heading row.

Click Insert->Table

Make sure "My table has headers" is checked.

You'll then be able to filter each of the columns using the Sub Header drop downs.

Alternatively click Data->Filter and filter out the H's. The Sub Headers will show up as data values though...